# How can I keep a keypress from propagating

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a viewstack which implements a 'wizard' interface for doing new orders.  On the last page of the wizard, there is a button, with a fake accelerator on it, by which, if they press 'o', they can start the process over again.

Below is my handler:

```
        protected function _keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if((e.charCode == 111)) {
                // stop the 'o' from getting out 
                trace("Cancelable : " , e.cancelable);
                this.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyDownHandler, true);
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                model.orderNew();
            }

        }
```

The problem is that when the user gets back to page 1 of the wizard, the 'o' the user just typed is now entered into a datagrid filtering textbox (filter by last names starting with 'o'), which is not what is desired.

As you can see, I've made some attempts at forbidding this interaction, but it appears to be not enough, even though the `model.orderNew()` bit contains all the code to swap the viewstack pages around, re-setting the focus to the txtSearchFilter, etc...I'm quite stymied!

It appears that e.cancelable == false, which is probably why I'm getting this behavior..but the documentation says that KEY_DOWN *IS* cancelable, so...I'm still lost.

How can I keep the keypress from propagating to the form ?

Thanks

Comment: closer reading of the documentaion says that its cancelable in AIR, not in flash....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/434862

It appears that both the KEY_DOWN and KEY_UP events are not cancellable in the flash player.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing the listener to use 'capture' mode instead of bubbling.

```
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyDownHandler, true);
```

See the AS3 reference on [addEventListener()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) for more details.

---

**EDIT:**  Actually, that might not be the direct issue. Instead, you might need to cancel the `KEY_UP` event, and do so on the common ancestor of the views.  You would still need to use capture mode.

Comment: And possibly you might need to register your listener with the high (or even highest) priority to prevent other capture-phase listeners from triggering. It depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: nope, that didn't do it.  I added  the capture mode AND a high priority (999), and the dratted 'o' keeps getting through.  What do you mean about canceling the KEY_UP event...  that sounds like a better possibility....

Comment: Hmm...it appears that KEY_UP is not cancelable...key down is, though...so, how do you cancel it...isn't that what e.PreventDefault() is for?  Yes, the docs say it is so...so, why doesn't it work?  What am I missing.

Comment: @reidLinden - Hmm. Yes, turns out you're right: only the KEY_DOWN is cancelable, and that is only in AIR.  However, you should still be able to capture and prevent it from propagating down into the TextInput's.  One problem though, I tried to do a test where I switched a view in the ViewStack based on a key input, but I'm wasn't able to recreate your bug.  Could you share more code, specifically where you have handler attached, any focus management you are doing, and wherever you actually change the ViewStack's selectedIndex?

Comment: I would, but its just a nasty mess of code, relying on event propagation via Mate, and other stuff.  I can't really distill it down to something sharable, at least, not *QUICKLY*

Answer (score 0):

if((e.charCode == 111)) {
removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN ...
}

and then reenable it when you need it again whenever you want (like when you put the focus on some other field)